# sencha touch: Tab with no icon

Tags: layout, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to create a item in a tabbar-ed card layout, that has no tab?

I want to create a message overlay that stretches from screen top to the tab bar and doesn't cover the tab bar. When i do this by adding an item to the panel everything works fine except a blank icon is created on the tabbar. Is there a way to prevent this icon from being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create the new item with **hidden: true** config option

```
Ext.define('App.view.settings.SettingsContainer', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'settingsContainer',

requires : [
...
],

config: {
    tabBar: {
        docked: 'top'
    },
    tab: {
        title: 'Settings',
        iconCls: 'user'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'settingsAccountContainer'
    }
    , {
        xtype: 'changeCompanyView',
        hidden: true
    }]
}
});
```

changeCompanyView is created, but no tab icon is visible.
It could be activated by

```
settingsContainer.setActiveItem(1);
```

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: perfect, thanks! Do you know where I can find this in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Add the overlay to the child item and not the tab panel.

```
childPanelItem.add(
    Ext.create('Ext.Panel',  
        {
            xtype:'panel',
            html:'Demo',
            top:0,
            left:0,
            right:0,
            bottom:0
        }
    )
);
```

If you add to the child panel the icon will not appear on the tab bar.